# Is correct add tags to questions once the problem has been indentified?

Tags: discussion, tags

Sometimes OP really ask questions without a complete knowledge about the error they have to face.

I was wondering how legit will be to add a tag to a solved question once the **real** problem has been identified.

For instance, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157332/unresolved-external-symbol-error-c) question we could maybe add the [linkage] tag. I know this is not the best example, but I think it represents quite well what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: This is second time I've post a question in Meta and is a dup. I always try to do some research about and don't find anything related, but in fact it exists... I'm a terrible researcher :(